# C# print pixel value

Tags: c#, image

I have a 8 bit bitmap color image. when i do a

```
Color pixelcolor = b.GetPixel(j,i);    
Console.Write(pixelcolor.ToString() + " " );
```

I get

```
 Color [A=255, R=255, G=255, B=255]
```

I need to get only the 8 bit value. not 24 bit seperate values for R,G,B ,A.

Comment: Is the image 8 bit indexed or non-indexed?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I've honestly never encountered a non-indexed 8bpp format. It would mean having only 2 or 3 bits for each colour component, which is a bit too small to store meaningful colour information.

Comment: @Nyerguds - Not encountering it doesn't mean it is not possible according to the specs. A monochrome or four color image isn't that far fetched at all.

Comment: There are no .Net color formats that support such a thing, though, making these possibilities irrelevant for images loaded in .Net. And monochrome 8-bit is technically still seen as indexed by .Net; the palette is simply filled with 256 gray values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do this using the `Bitmap` class directly. However, you can use the `LockBits` method to access the pixels directly.

Using [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) code: (remember to [enable unsafe code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct597kb0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in your project first)

```
public static unsafe Byte GetIndexedPixel(Bitmap b, Int32 x, Int32 y)
{
    if (b.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed) throw new ArgumentException("Image is not in 8 bit per pixel indexed format!");
    if (x < 0 || x >= b.Width) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("x", string.Format("x should be in 0-{0}", b.Width));
    if (y < 0 || y >= b.Height) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("y", string.Format("y should be in 0-{0}", b.Height));
    BitmapData data = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, b.PixelFormat);
    try
    {
        Byte* scan0 = (Byte*)data.Scan0;
        return scan0[x + y * data.Stride];
    }
    finally
    {
        if (data != null) b.UnlockBits(data);
    }
}
```

The safe alternative, using `Marshal.Copy`:

```
public static Byte GetIndexedPixel(Bitmap b, Int32 x, Int32 y)
{
    if (b.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed) throw new ArgumentException("Image is not in 8 bit per pixel indexed format!");
    if (x < 0 || x >= b.Width) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("x", string.Format("x should be in 0-{0}", b.Width));
    if (y < 0 || y >= b.Height) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("y", string.Format("y should be in 0-{0}", b.Height));
    BitmapData data = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, b.PixelFormat);
    try
    {
        Byte[] pixel = new Byte[1];
        Marshal.Copy(new IntPtr(data.Scan0.ToInt64() + x + y * data.Stride), pixel, 0, 1);
        return pixel[0];
    }
    finally
    {
        if (data != null) b.UnlockBits(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can avoid unsafe by using `Marshal.Copy` to get the bytes out.

Comment: Yeah, but it's annoying having to copy the entire buffer just to query one pixel. But normally most if not all pixels are read, so in this case Marshal.Copy is a great way to go.

Comment: Yeah... using this code as it is has the same often-remarked problem of the normal `GetPixel`: when looping over all content, having to lock and unlock for each pixel, on an image which can have thousands or even ten thousands of pixels, is notoriously slow, whereas just checking the contents of a byte array is lightning fast.

Comment: Mind you... can't you just use `Marshal.Copy` to copy out exactly one byte at `x + y*data.Stride`?

Comment: I guess you could; for people who don't want to (or can't) use `unsafe`, it's a useful addition.

Comment: @Nyerguds I don't know if my C# level is good enough to change it now. Also I don't have a C# IDE available. Perhaps you can help out by suggesting an edit?

Comment: Ah, too much experience in c#; I can't _suggest_ edits anymore; I just edit directly. Anyway, I added it. I fixed the pixel format too; "indexed" isn't valid in this case; it's a group of all possible indexed formats. You need to take the image's actual pixel format here. Another thing I realized while doing this (but I didn't add it) was that you can actually just lock exactly that one pixel, if you lock on `new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1)`. Then `data.Scan0` is the exact address of the byte you need ;)

Comment: Ah, there is one small remark on this: it only works on 8bpp, For 4bpp or 1bpp you'd need to adjust the x-index to multiple pixels compacted into single bytes, and extract the exact intended bits from the target byte, which is a lot more complex. The question only asked about 8bpp, though, so it's not particularly relevant here, but I edited the `PixelFormat` check at the start to correctly represent the 8bpp requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The methods in the `Bitmap` class doesn't let you get the palette index directly.

You can get the palette for the image using the `Palette` property, and look for the color there, but that's a bit of a workaround.

To get the palette index directly, you would use the `LockBits` method to get access to the image data directly. You would either have to use marshalling to copy the data into an array, or use pointers in unsafe mode to access it.

---

The `A` property in a `Color` value is the Alpha component. It can have the value 0 to 255, where 0 is fully transparent and 255 is fully solid.

Answer (score -1):

The values you want are actually `R`, `G` and `B`, which are 8bit bitmap values of corresponding `Red`, `Green` and `Blue` components of the color.

`A` is a `Alfa` coponent, the transparency value of the color. If you don't care about it, just don't show it in string output.

Comment: On 8-bit indexed bitmaps, pixels do not contain the data for R, G, B and A; that would require _multiple_ 8-bit values, which would make the image 24 or 32 bit per pixel. Each pixel in an 8-bit image is a _single_ 8-bit value, which is an _index_ to look up in the image's colour palette.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use LockBits, you can do this:

**Warning**: This method only works if the palette does not have duplicated values and if it is not changed by another thread after pixelRGB is set.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the pixel value in bytes. Uses Bitmap GetPixel method.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bmp">Bitmap</param>
/// <param name="location">Pixel location</param>
/// <returns>Pixel value</returns>
public static byte Get8bppImagePixel(Bitmap bmp, Point location)
{
    Color pixelRGB = bmp.GetPixel(location.X, location.Y);
    int pixel8bpp = Array.IndexOf(bmp.Palette.Entries, pixelRGB);
    return (byte)pixel8bpp;
}
```

Comment: This is not reliable if the palette has duplicates.

Comment: @Nyerguds the code uses the current bitmap palette. The only problem would be if another thread change the palled after getting pixelRGB.

Comment: No, I mean, Palette.Entries can literally contain the same colour multiple times. If a pixel has a certain colour but it appears on the palette twice, and that pixel happens to use the second occurrence, then this code fails to get the correct index. One way around this would be to set the image's palette to a gray fade before this operation, and restore it afterwards.

Comment: @Nyerguds Oh, I got it now. Yes you are right. I'm going to add this observation to my answer.